# Which signal should I handle and how?

Tags: c, shell, signals, dry, signal-handling

Where in my code should I "wait until children are finished "? I have a C program that is similar to a custom shell. Now I have a builtin function `checkEnv` that can print the sorted environment variables. So I can start my shell and list my environment variables:

```
$ ./a.out 
miniShell>> checkEnv
"'><;|&(:
_=./a.out
CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE=ubuntu
COMP_WORDBREAKS=        
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-mh5oMhyCI6
DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path
DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu
```

The code behind that does this is the following:

```
 if(StartsWith(line, "checkEnv")) {
     built_in_command=1;
     pagerValue = getenv ("PAGER");
     if (! pagerValue) {
       if (ret == 0) {
         pager_cmd[0]="less";
       } else {
         pager_cmd[0]="more";
       }
     }
    else {
     pager_cmd[0]=pagerValue;
    }


    if(i==1) {
       cmd[0].argv= printenv;
       cmd[1].argv= sort;
       cmd[2].argv= pager_cmd;
       fork_pipes(3, cmd);


    }
    else {

     for (k = 1; k < i; k++)
    {
         len += strlen(argv2[k]) + 2;
    }
    tmp = (char *) malloc(len);
    tmp[0] = '\0';
    for (k = 1; k < i; k++)
    {
       pos += sprintf(tmp + pos, "%s%s", (k == 1 ? "" : "|"), argv2[k]);
    }
    grep[0]="grep";
    grep[1]="-E";
    grep[2]= tmp;
    grep[3]= NULL;
    cmd2[0].argv= printenv;
    cmd2[1].argv= grep;
    cmd2[2].argv= sort;
    cmd2[3].argv= pager_cmd;
    fork_pipes(4, cmd2);
    free(tmp);

            }
```

Now I want to catch the output termination signal when listing the environment variables using the pager so that the program returns to the custom shell instead of terminating the whole program. So I suppose that I should use some signal handling but how and which signal?

The actual fork is from this function.

```
/* Helper function that forks pipes */
void fork_pipes(int n, struct command *cmd) {
    int i;
    int in = 0;
    int fd[2];
    /** loop and fork() */
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {

        if (pipe(fd) == -1) {
            err_syserr("Failed creating pipe");
        }

        spawn_proc(in, fd[1], cmd + i);
        close(fd[1]);
        in = fd[0];
    }
    if (dup2(in, 0) < 0) {
        err_syserr("dup2() failed on stdin for %s: ", cmd[i].argv[0]);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "%d: executing %s\n", (int) getpid(), cmd[i].argv[0]);
    execvp(cmd[i].argv[0], cmd[i].argv);
    err_syserr("failed to execute %s: ", cmd[i].argv[0]);
}
```

Where should the signal handling go? Where is a minimal working example of what I'm trying to do? I see no example that does this and I think the documentation is terrible, only snippets and no complete example.

My helper function is

```
/* Helper function that spawns processes */
int spawn_proc(int in, int out, struct command *cmd) {
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        if (in != 0) {
            if (dup2(in, 0) < 0)
                err_syserr("dup2() failed on stdin for %s: ", cmd->argv[0]);
            close(in);
        }
        if (out != 1) {
            if (dup2(out, 1) < 0)
                err_syserr("dup2() failed on stdout for %s: ", cmd->argv[0]);
            close(out);
        }
        printf("** we are executing parent ***");
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: executing %s\n", (int) getpid(), cmd->argv[0]);
        execvp(cmd->argv[0], cmd->argv);
        err_syserr("failed to execute %s: ", cmd->argv[0]);
    }
    else if (pid < 0) {
        err_syserr("fork failed: ");
    } else {
        /* */
         printf("** we are the parent ***");
    }
    return pid;
}
```

My `main()` now looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    sourceCount = 0;
    const char *commandFile;

    commandFile = NULL;
    char *pathValue;
/*    struct sigaction sa, osa;
    struct sigaction sa2;*/
    int errflag;
    int cOption;
    struct sigaction action;
    /* use getopt_long()  */
    char *argv1[] = {"version", "par2", 0};
/*    char *argv2[] = {"help", "-m", "arg1", 0};*/

    /* use sigaction */

    sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask);
    action.sa_handler = handle_sigchld;
    action.sa_flags = 0;

    sigaction(SIGPIPE, &action, NULL);   //Not work with kill -13 process_id
    //works well
    sigaction(SIGINT, &action, NULL);    //work with kill -2 process_id

    errflag = 0;

    /* use getopt_long()  */
    while ((cOption = getopt(2, argv1, "m:t:n:fs?")) != -1) {

        switch (cOption) {
            case 'a':
                printf("apples\n");
                break;
            case 'b':
                printf("bananas\n");
                break;
            case 't':
                printf("tree = %s\n", optarg);
                break;
            case '?':
                ++errflag;
                break;
        }
    }
/*
    while (( cOption = getopt (3, argv2, "m:t:n:fs?")) != -1) {
        switch (cOption) {
            case 'm':
                printf("\n Help msg : %s \n", optarg);
                exit(0);
            case '?':
                printf("\n -? Arg : %s \n", optarg);
                break;
            case 'n':
                printf("\n -n Arg : %s \n", optarg);
                break;
        }
    }
*/


    /* get the PATH environment to find if less is installed */
    pathValue = getenv("PATH");
    if (!pathValue || getenv("PATH") == NULL) {
        printf("'%s' is not set.\n", "PATH");

        /* Default our path if it is not set. */

        putenv("PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/etc");
    }
    else {
        printf("'%s' is set to %s.\n", "PATH", pathValue);
    }
    exec_program(commandFile);
    return (0);
}
```

If I run my shell in `gdb` I get a normal exit.

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/dac/ClionProjects/shell2/openshell/shell 
'PATH' is set to /home/dac/proj/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin.
dac:/home/dac/ClionProjects/shell2/openshell $ checkenv
7429: executing printenv
7430: executing grep
7417: executing less
7431: executing sort
process 7417 is executing new program: /bin/less
[Inferior 1 (process 7417) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

Comment: What signal is causing your program to terminate? SIGPIPE? Your real shell should tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the parent, you should not need to receive any signal, just call wait() until it returns that your child has died and is now reaped. Your shell is now ready to perform a new task.

your code in the original request if very incomplete, so here comes one example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wait.h>

void foobar()
{
  int pipe_fd[2];
  pid_t pid1, pid2;

  pipe(pipe_fd);

  pid1=fork();
  if (pid1 == 0)
  {
    /* child1 - let us pretend that we wanted to replace stdin and this child */
    close (0);
    dup(pipe_fd[0]);
    close(pipe_fd[0]);
    close(pipe_fd[1]);
    execlp("wc", "wc", NULL);
    perror ("execlp(wc)");
    _exit(0);
  }

  pid2=fork();
  if (pid2 == 0)
  {
    /* child - let us pretent that we wanted to replace stdout */
    close (1);
    dup(pipe_fd[1]);
    close(pipe_fd[0]);
    close(pipe_fd[1]);
    execlp("ls", "ls", "-l", NULL);
    perror ("execlp(ls)");
    _exit(0);
  }

  close(pipe_fd[0]);
  close(pipe_fd[1]);

  /* wait until children are finished */
  while ((pid1 >= 0) || (pid2 >= 0))
  {
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    pid = wait(&status);
    if (pid < 0)
    {
      continue;
    }
    if (pid == pid1)
    {
      pid1 = -1;
    }
    if (pid == pid2)
    {
      pid2 = -1;
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        foobar();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I just had to `fork` and wait now that I know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

You want to catch `SIGCHLD`, and reap the child status with one of the `wait()` functions.

The following info is from an [online tutorial](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/reap_zombie_processes_using_a_sigchld_handler.html).

> ```
> void handle_sigchld(int sig) {
>     int saved_errno = errno;
>     while (waitpid((pid_t)(-1), 0, WNOHANG) > 0) {}
>     errno = saved_errno;
> }
>
> struct sigaction sa;
> sa.sa_handler = &handle_sigchld;
> sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
> sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART | SA_NOCLDSTOP;
> if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, 0) == -1) {
>     perror(0);
>     exit(1);
> }
> ```

Also, you will likely want to ignore `SIGPIPE`.

> ```
> struct sigaction sa;
> sa.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
> sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
> sa.sa_flags = 0;
> if (sigaction(SIGPIPE, &sa, 0) == -1) {
>   perror(0);
>   exit(1);
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please can you elaborate a little? I have not done this before and I am not a C expert.

Comment: @Programmer400 There is  a link to the tutorial. I don't think there is any point of copying any more of it here...

Comment: @EugeneSh. I don't understand _where_ in the code I should `wait()` so I'm awarding abounty for details.

Comment: The signal handler `handle_sigchld` is calling `waitpid`, which is one of the `wait` functions.

Comment: Where should the signal handling code go? I have signal handler that works to keep the program running at a `ctrl+c` but it is impossible to catch the `less` program from exiting the whole shell. The documentation is really terrible - I see no example of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Signal handlers are typically installed near the top of `main`. You may need to handle more than one signal. Ctrl-C generates `SIGINT`. Signals may interrupt your system call, and `errno` is set to `EINTR`. If that happens, redo the call again. This is all information that can be found in a UNIX programming text book, which perhaps you should find and browse for more background.

Comment: Should the 2 variables named `sa` be same or different for two different signal handlers? I posted my code from main that works for sigint but not for keeping the shell running after a builtin command executes.

Comment: @jxh Ok so I'm working the `main` trying to enable the `SIGPIPE` because I remember that used to work before I did a large refactoring. I'm starting a builtin command that starts a pipeline of command from `/bin` and I can't keep the shell running when the last program ('less`) in the pipeline finishes.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood my answer. I provided a technique to reap spawned children. I provided advice on dealing with writing to a closed connection. You did not ask a *why doesn't my program work* question. If you intended to, consider posting a new question.

Comment: @jxh All I wanted was to keep the shell running. I will again how to achieve that in a new question. Thank you for the help.